# Playwright Compare screenshot against existing image

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

1. take clip screenshort
2. compare screenshort against existing picture stored in my repo

```
const screenshot = await page.screenshot({ clip: { height: 20, width: 20, x: 630, y: 283 }, path: `${name}Icon.png`})

expect(screenshot).toMatchSnapshot('ExistingIconPicture.png');
```

getting error >ExistingIconPicture-chromium-win32.png is missing in snapshots, writing actual.

How to compare against already existing picture?

Edit: To make it clear enough, I want to compare taken screenshot with specific existing picture. So lets say I have existing picture icon 'Icon.png' and I want to compare clip screenshot with this icon 'Icon.png'. But I want to do that in multiple different tests, so the existing picture('Icon.png') cannot follow the name based on running test.

```
const screenshot = await page.screenshot({ clip: { height: 20, width: 20, x: 630, y: 283 }, path: ${page}Icon.png}) 

expect(screenshot).toMatchSnapshot('Icon.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either your file is missing the full file name it expects (the chromium win32 part), or it isn’t in the directory it expects. See [the Playwright docs on how it handles toMatchSnapshot and other visual comparisons](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-snapshots).

Comment: My question was not propbably clear enough, I want to compare taken screenshot with specific existing picture. So lets say I have existing picture icon 'Icon.png' and I want to compare clip screenshot with this icon 'Icon.png'. But I want to do that in multiple different tests, so the existing picture('Icon.png') cannot follow the name based on running test.                    `const screenshot = await page.screenshot({ clip: { height: 20, width: 20, x: 630, y: 283 }, path: `${name}Icon.png`})

expect(screenshot).toMatchSnapshot('Icon.png');`